# Connection Refused Issue with Apache Camel RabbitMQ new URI format using SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, apache-camel

I have developed a simple producer-consumer application using Spring Boot + Apache Camel + Apache Camel RabbitMQ. I have used the old URI format (which is deprecated now) which is working fine. But When I change the syntax with new URI format it shows the following error:-

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:60) ~[amqp-client-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.newConnection(RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.java:62) ~[amqp-client-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.init(AutorecoveringConnection.java:156) ~[amqp-client-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1095) ~[amqp-client-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1054) ~[amqp-client-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1012) ~[amqp-client-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1201) ~[amqp-client-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQEndpoint.connect(RabbitMQEndpoint.java:221) ~[camel-rabbitmq-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQConsumer.openConnection(RabbitMQConsumer.java:64) ~[camel-rabbitmq-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQConsumer.getConnection(RabbitMQConsumer.java:73) ~[camel-rabbitmq-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitConsumer.reconnect(RabbitConsumer.java:316) ~[camel-rabbitmq-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQConsumer$StartConsumerCallable.call(RabbitMQConsumer.java:218) [camel-rabbitmq-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQConsumer$StartConsumerCallable.call(RabbitMQConsumer.java:198) [camel-rabbitmq-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_232]

2019-12-24 11:35:01.553  INFO 8269 --- [-QUEUE.exchange] o.a.c.component.rabbitmq.RabbitConsumer  : Attempting to open a new rabbitMQ channel
2019-12-24 11:35:01.557  INFO 8269 --- [-QUEUE.exchange] o.a.c.c.rabbitmq.RabbitMQConsumer        : Connection failed, will retry in 5000ms
```

This is my **pom.xml** file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>io.arun.learning</groupId>
    <artifactId>producer-consumer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId> <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId> 
            <version>2.24.2</version> </dependency> -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-spring-boot-starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-RC3</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-rabbitmq</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is my Spring Boot Application main class:-

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ProducerConsumerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProducerConsumerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My **RabbitConfig.java** class

```
@Component
public class RabbitMQConfig extends RouteBuilder{

    JacksonDataFormat jacksonDataFormat = new JacksonDataFormat(User.class);

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

   //Old URI which is absolutely working fine...

//      from("direct:rabbitMQStart").id("rabbitRoute").marshal(jacksonDataFormat)
//          .to("rabbitmq://localhost:5672/TEST-QUEUE.exchange?autoDelete=false&routingKey=myRoute1").end();
//      
//      from("rabbitmq://localhost:5672/TEST-QUEUE.exchange?queue=javainuse.queue&autoDelete=false&routingKey=myRoute1").unmarshal(jacksonDataFormat)
//          .to("bean:io.arun.learning.camel.service.UserService?method=addUser");
//      

    // New URI format which is not working....
        from("direct:rabbitMQStart").id("rabbitRoute").marshal(jacksonDataFormat)
            .to("rabbitmq:TEST-QUEUE.exchange?autoDelete=false");

        from("rabbitmq:TEST-QUEUE.exchange?queue=javainuse.queue&autoDelete=false").unmarshal(jacksonDataFormat)
            .to("bean:io.arun.learning.camel.service.UserService?method=addUser");

    }

}
```

My **UserController.java** class

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Produce(uri = "direct:rabbitMQStart")
    private ProducerTemplate producer;

    @PostMapping("/users")
    public String pushUserIntoQueue(@RequestBody User user) {
        Future<Object> status = producer.asyncSendBody(producer.getDefaultEndpoint(), user);
        return status.toString();
    }

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public List<UserDto> getUsersFromQueue() {
        return UserService.getUsers();
    }

}
```

My **UserDto.java** class

```
public class UserDto {
    private LocalDateTime receivedAt;
    private User user;

    public UserDto() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public UserDto(LocalDateTime receivedAt, User user) {
        super();
        this.receivedAt = receivedAt;
        this.user = user;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getReceivedAt() {
        return receivedAt;
    }

    public void setReceivedAt(LocalDateTime receivedAt) {
        this.receivedAt = receivedAt;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

My **User.java** class

```
public class User {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(int id, String name, int age) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", age=" + age + "]";
    }

}
```

My **UserService.java** class

```
public class UserService {

    public static List<UserDto> users = new ArrayList<UserDto>();

    public void addUser(User user) {
        users.add(new UserDto(LocalDateTime.now(), user));
        System.out.println("Received User:" + user);
    }

    public static List<UserDto> getUsers(){
        return users;
    }

}
```

Anybody can help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the output. We must register the ConnectionFactory to the spring container before we use the new URI as follows:-

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ProducerConsumerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProducerConsumerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        ConnectionFactory con = new ConnectionFactory();
        con.setHost("localhost");
        return con;
    }
}
```

Thanks! I hope it helps!